# How to sort list by first element

Tags: r, list

I have a list of vectors looking like:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 1.0 3.0

[[2]]
[1] 3 3 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 3.0 1.0
```

and I want it to be sorted by first element of every vector, in decreasing order, like that:

```
[[1]]
[1] 3 3 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 1.0 3.0    

[[3]]
[1] 1 3.0 1.0
```

I am looking for a solution that would look like (of course it is not working):

```
list.sortby(function (x) x[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed that your example should not have resulted in putting the second element of your list in the first element of the result? If this is right, you can use `lapply`to do what you want:

```
L <- list(c(2,1,3), c(3,3,3), c(1,3,1))
L
lapply(L, sort)
```

If you are ordering by the first value in each vector of you list, then this can be done in the following way:

```
L[order(sapply(L, function(x) x[1], simplify=TRUE), decreasing=TRUE)]

L
[[1]]
[1] 3 3 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 1 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 3 1
```

From your example, it looks like you want the decreasing order.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @MarkintheBox.

```
L <- list(c(2,1,3), c(3,3,3), c(1,3,1))

L[order(sapply(L,head,1),decreasing=T)]
# [[1]]
# [1] 3 3 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 1 3
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as the others but using Map to extract the first element of each vector.

```
L <- list(c(2,1,3), c(3,3,3), c(1,3,1))
idx <- as.numeric(Map(function(vec){vec[1]},L))
L[order(idx, decreasing=TRUE)]
```